# GridView sorting with additional functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

I have a GridView which is bound automaticaly to a SqlDataSource. I have a function which goes thru the GridView and colors red certain cells according to their content. I also enabled sorting on the GridView on all columns. When the page first loads the function coloring appropriate cells works. When I click the column header to sort, it sorts, but  the cells that should be colored doen't get colored. I tried putting the call to the coloring function in the Page_Load in an if(isPostBack) condition and I tried using the GridView_Sorted event putting the call to the coloring function in there. None of that worked. I also tried adding GridView1.DataBind() in both the Page_Load and GridView_Sorted events before calling the coloring function and after. In all scenarios sorting worked but coloring did not!
How can I get both sorting and coloring working?
Thank you.

Comment: Put your coloring logic into [GridView's RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter that's great it did the job! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To enable accepting the answer, i copy my comment here:*

Put your coloring logic into [GridView's RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

Comment: Thank you for enabling me to accept your answer! I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Put the coloring in the OnRowDataBound event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Coloring the cells this way, it will happen *during* the databinding.